# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call and loop

Tags: python

I don't know how to find a series value by using the fsolve()...How to write correct one

```
def F(x):
    return 1-x*np.cos(x)/np.sin(x)-c

c=5.0

for i in range(5):
    ResidualArray.append(i)
    lambda0.append(i)=fsolve(F,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to collect `fsolve` (whatever that function does) return values in a list (not initialized in your code) named `lambda0`.  If so, then you can do it this way:

```
lambda0.append(fsolve(F,i))
```